# Given the following schema, what would be the query to print all students in a teachers class?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Schema:

[image: Schema]

This is what I'm thinking, but I don't think its right:

```
SELECT distinct t.teacherid, s.fname

FROM tea_cou t,  students s, stu_cou c

WHERE  t.courseid = c.courseid
```

Comment: It's not right, you're right. You need to reference the columns from the tables you're joining to each other

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables and then filter by teacher name.

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM Teachers T 
INNER JOIN Tea_Cou TC ON Tc.TeacherId = T.TeacherId 
INNER JOIN Courses C ON C.CourseId= TC.CourseId 
INNER JOIN Stu_Cou SC ON SC.CourseId = C.CourseId 
INNER JOIN Students S ON S.StudentId = SC.StudentId 
WHERE T.LNAME= 'name'
```